# How to open a file in QWebView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am developing a Web Development program using the Qt5 framework and C++. It needs a feature that lets the user see how the webpage looks like, without opening a Web Browser.

This is the code I am using `ui->webView->load("file://" + filename);` and it's not working.

Comment: try with: `ui->webView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));`

Comment: QWebView? Is this thing still around? Why not `QWebEngineView`?